# Camera's extrinsic matrix

Tags: camera, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I am trying to use MATLAB's camera calibrator to calibrate an infrared camera. I was able to get the intrinsic matrix by just feeding around 100 images to the calibrator. But I'm struggling with how to get the extrinsic matrix [R|t].

Because the extrinsic matrix is used to map the world frame with the camera frame, so in theory, when the camera(object) is moving, there will be many extrinsic matrices.

In the picture below, if the intrinsic matrix is determined using 50 images, then there are 50 extrinsic matrices correspond to each image. Am I correct?

[image: the calibration session]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Usually, a by-product of an intrinsic calibration is the extrinsic matrix for each pattern observed; this is mostly used to draw the patterns with respect to the camera as in the picture you posted.

What you usually do afterwards is to define some external reference frame that makes sense for you application, also known as the 'world' reference frame, and compute the pose of the camera with respect to it. That's *the* extrinsic matrix you always hear about.

For this, you:

- Define the reference frame and take some points with known 3D coordinates on it;   this can be a grid drawn on the floor, for example.
- Take a picture of the 3D points with the calibrated camera and get a list of the correspondent 2D (image) coordinates of the points.
- Use a pose estimation function that takes: the camera intrinsic parameters, the 3D points and the correspondent 2D image points. I am more familiar with OpenCV, but the Matlab function that seems to do the job is: https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimateworldcamerapose.html